# handling various file path using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the xml path /opt/Data/Configuration/test.xml in app and need to handle the path in docker and my simulator path is system/DataProgram/Device/config/test.xml

in docker I have to tell docker to use system/DataProgram/Device/config/test.xml instead of /opt/Data/Configuration/test.xml